# How to identify actual IP from VIP

Tags: ip

I want to figure out whether an IP - 122.171.212.100 is a virtual IP (the actual ip is hidden behind this vip) or its an actual IP which can be tracked to figure out the person behind this IP.

How I can identify the person behind this IP. This is related to a fraud case any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything wrong woth the question i have asked ?

Comment: as i do not see any reply

Comment: Your question is most probably out of scope for this site (no coding example, nothing to do with programming). You don´t even state what you have tried so far... there are many sites out there that will let you check IP addresses and even consult blacklistings... the IP you mention is located in Bangalore, is probably a dynamic address (i.e not fixed to a specific machcine) and is blacklisted as spammer (because the company hosts many spammers)... Just type the IP into your preferred search engine and look at the results. Contacting local authorities might be your only chance to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Its not that I havent tried anything I have looked at the IP http://whois.domaintools.com/122.171.212.100 and found that its from bangalore, but I am just thinking out loud and figuring out what  if its a VIP and the actual IP is somewhere else not even in India some other country,in which case I forget about my fraud and live with it and if it is within India there is chance in million to catch the thief.

Comment: Short answer - you cannot. For some protocols you probably can get some information for host behind but they are rather exception than rule.